# How to enable proper C++ linting for modules in VS Code (Linux)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, module, intellisense, c++20

I'm using **VS Code** on my **Manjaro Linux** machine to write C++ code. Since I'd like to use C++20 syntax and modules for my next project, I went into my settings and set `C_CPP > Default: Cpp Standard` to `c++20`.

However when writing this test snippet (which compiled just fine using g++)

```cpp
import <iostream>;

auto main() -> int {
    std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

code highlighting and linting does not work as expected.

[image: linter not working]

Is there any way to get working on VS Code?

Comment: @TheBeautifulOrc I don't know whether any tooling currently supports that out-of-the-box. Which compiler do you intent to use? Most of them don't support it out-of-the-box yet either. For example with GCC you will need to generate the header units manually before you can compile that.

Comment: "highlighting and linting" is nothing but hints and suggestions. Don't rely on it

Comment: @user17732522 Yes, I'm aware that I need to generate my std-modules beforehand. However the compilation itself works fine with the -fmodule-ts flag.

Comment: @TheBeautifulOrc I haven't tried myself, but I doubt that the linting will currently work. The tool needs to understand the mapping of header units to files, which is compiler-specific. So IntelliSense would need to understand GCC's convention (or be aware that `<iostream>` is a standard header unit). I think currently it doesn't even fully work with MSVC.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Well, syntax highlighting is neither a hint nor a suggestion but a visual aid to navigate your code. I find it rather helpful. Same goes for linting, it just helps to catch some errors before starting a compile. I know that autocompletion is a debated topic, but I'm quite fond of it. While I could write code without those features, I would be significantly slower and more prone to make errors, so they're a net plus for me.

Comment: According to https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/6302 it still has issues with the MSVC compiler and quote question/answer: "_Is there now support for c++20 modules for gcc/clang in addition to ifc?_" "_Not yet._".

Comment: @user17732522 Hey, thanks for digging that out! Do you know if clang-tidy is a little more mature in that regard?

Comment: @TheBeautifulOrc I don't know and haven't tried it. But I guess chances are higher that it will support GCC's module conventions.